# Sending a message from Raspberry PI to Android device using Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I want to have a button on Raspberry PI to send a message to Android device using Bluetooth.

Is it possible by using the Raspberry PI or I should look for another IoT hardware?

Comment: The Pi 3 would be ideal as it has on-board Bluetooth. There are also lots of tutorials based around the Raspberry Pi, so with a bit of research I'm sure you will find what you need.

Comment: You even have a choice to use standard Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy! I have successfully done BLE from Pi to Android and iOS apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have achieved this by creating a Raspberry Pi Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral device. The code is on Github for the [Raspberry Pi peripheral](https://github.com/qbalsdon/BLE_Rpi_Peripheral) and for the accompanying [Android app](https://github.com/qbalsdon/BLE_Android). Just make sure your raspberry pi is up to date.

Raspberry Pi Bluetooth Ble Peripheral with Bleno:

```
var bleno = require('bleno');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var CHUNK_SIZE = 20;

var Descriptor = bleno.Descriptor;

var deviceName = 'RaspberrPi3';
var myId = '4afb720a-5214-4337-841b-d5f954214877';
var data = new Buffer('Send me some data to display');
var output = "";
var updateCallback;

var terminalCallback;
var terminalResponse;

var START_CHAR = String.fromCharCode(002); //START OF TEXT CHAR
var END_CHAR = String.fromCharCode(003);   //END OF TEXT CHAR

function sliceUpResponse(callback, responseText) {
  if (!responseText || !responseText.trim()) return;
  callback(new Buffer(START_CHAR));
  while(responseText !== '') {
      callback(new Buffer(responseText.substring(0, CHUNK_SIZE)));
      responseText = responseText.substring(CHUNK_SIZE);
  }
  callback(new Buffer(END_CHAR));
}

var terminal = new bleno.Characteristic({
    uuid : '8bacc104-15eb-4b37-bea6-0df3ac364199',
    properties : ['write','read','notify'],
    onReadRequest : function(offset, callback) {
        console.log("Read request");
        callback(bleno.Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS, new Buffer(terminalResponse).slice(offset));
    },
    onWriteRequest : function(newData, offset, withoutResponse, callback) {
        if(offset) {
            callback(bleno.Characteristic.RESULT_ATTR_NOT_LONG);
        } else {
            var data = newData.toString('utf8');
            console.log("Command received: [" + data + "]");
            dir = exec(data, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    var stringError = JSON.stringify(err);
                    console.log(stringError);
                    callback(bleno.Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS);
                    terminalResponse = stringError;
                } else {
                    console.log(stdout);
                    callback(bleno.Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS);
                    terminalResponse = stdout;
                }
                if (terminalCallback) sliceUpResponse(terminalCallback, terminalResponse);
            });
        }
    },
    onSubscribe: function(maxValueSize, updateValueCallback) {
       console.log("onSubscribe called");
       terminalCallback = updateValueCallback;
    },
    onUnsubscribe: function() {
        terminalCallback = null;
        console.log("onUnsubscribe");
    }
});

bleno.on('stateChange', function(state) {
    console.log('on -> stateChange: ' + state);
    if (state === 'poweredOn') {
        bleno.startAdvertising(deviceName,[myId]);
    } else {
        bleno.stopAdvertising();
    }
});

bleno.on('advertisingStart', function(error) {
    console.log('on -> advertisingStart: ' + (error ? 'error ' + error : 'success'));
    if (!error) {
        bleno.setServices([
            new bleno.PrimaryService({
                uuid : myId,
                characteristics : [
                    // add characteristics here
                    terminal
                ]
            })
        ]);
        console.log('service added');
    }
});

bleno.on('accept', function(clientAddress) {
    console.log("Accepted connection from: " + clientAddress);
});

bleno.on('disconnect', function(clientAddress) {
    console.log("Disconnected from: " + clientAddress);
});
```

Android class for connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy device:

```
public class BLEPeripheral {

  private String mDeviceId;
  private BLEManager mConnector;
  private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
  private BluetoothLeScanner mBLEScanner;
  private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
  private BluetoothGattService mService = null;
  private HashMap<String, Command<String>> subscriptions;

  public BLEPeripheral(BLEManager connector, String deviceId) {
      mConnector = connector;
      mDeviceId = deviceId;

      mConnector.onDisconnected();
      final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mConnector.getContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
      mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

      if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
          mConnector.enableBluetooth();
          return;
      }

      if (!mConnector.checkPermission()) return;

      scanForDevice();
  }

  public void scanForDevice() {
      mConnector.log("BT ENABLED: SCANNING FOR DEVICES");
      mBLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
      mBLEScanner.startScan(mLEScanCallback);
  }

  public void stopScan() {
      mBLEScanner.stopScan(mLEScanCallback);
  }

  private ScanCallback mLEScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
          BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
          ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();
          if (record == null) {
              mConnector.log(String.format("Device [%s] has no scan record", device.getAddress()));
              return;
          }

          String name = record.getDeviceName();
          String UUID = null;

          if (record.getServiceUuids() != null) {
              for (ParcelUuid pId : record.getServiceUuids()) {
                  if (pId.getUuid().toString().equals(mDeviceId)) {
                      UUID = pId.getUuid().toString();
                  }
              }
          }
          if (UUID == null) {
              mConnector.log(String.format("Discovered Device [%s]. Continuing search", name));
              return;
          }
          mConnector.log(String.format("Peripheral [%s] located on Device [%s]. Attempting connection", UUID, name));
          mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mConnector.getContext(), true, mGattCallback);
          stopScan();
          super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
      }
  };

  private void closeGatt() {
      mConnector.onDisconnected();
      if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
          return;
      }
      mBluetoothGatt.close();
      mBluetoothGatt = null;
      scanForDevice();
  }

  private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
      StringBuilder buffer;
              @Override
              public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                  mConnector.onConnectionStateChange(newState);
                  if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                      mConnector.log("Connected to device GATT. Discovering services");
                      mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                  } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                      mConnector.log("Disconnected from GATT server. Continuing scanning");
                      closeGatt();
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                  if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                      if (mBluetoothGatt.getServices() != null) {
                          for (BluetoothGattService service : mBluetoothGatt.getServices()) {
                              if (service.getUuid().toString().equals(mDeviceId)) {
                                  mService = service;
                                  mConnector.onConnected();
                                  mConnector.log("Service discovered");
                              }
                          }
                      }

                  } else {
                      mConnector.log(String.format("onServicesDiscovered received: [%s]", status));
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                  if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                      mConnector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicRead received: [%s] value: [%s]", characteristic.getUuid().toString(), new String(characteristic.getValue())));
                  } else {
                      mConnector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicRead fail received: [%s]", status));
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                  super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
                  if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                      mConnector.log(String.format("onCharacteristicWrite received: [%s] value: [%s]", characteristic.getUuid().toString(), new String(characteristic.getValue())));
                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                  String packet = new String(characteristic.getValue());
                  if (packet.equals(String.valueOf((char)2))) {
                      buffer = new StringBuilder();
                  } else if (packet.equals(String.valueOf((char)3))) {
                      //mConnector.log(String.format("Characteristic received: [%s] Value: [%s]", characteristic.getUuid().toString(), buffer.toString()));
                      if (subscriptions == null || subscriptions.size() == 0) return;

                      Command<String> handler = subscriptions.get(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                      if (handler != null) handler.execute(new String(buffer.toString()));
                  } else {
                      buffer.append(packet);
                  }
              }
          };

  public BluetoothGattService getService() {
      return mService;
  }

  private BluetoothGattCharacteristic findCharacteristicById(String id) {
      if (mService.getCharacteristics() != null) {
          return mService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString(id));
      }
      return null;
  }

  public void subscribe(String characteristicId, Command<String> handler){
      if (subscriptions == null) subscriptions = new HashMap<>();
      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);

      if (characteristic == null) {
          mConnector.log("Characteristic does not exist");
          return;
      }

      mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
      BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
      descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
      mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

      subscriptions.put(characteristicId, handler);
  }

  public void writeCharacteristic(String characteristicId, String data) {
      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);
      if (characteristic != null) {
          characteristic.setValue(data);
          mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
          mConnector.log(String.format("Wrote [%s] to [%s]", data, characteristicId));
      } else {
          mConnector.log(String.format("[%s] not found on device", characteristicId));
      }
  }

  public void readCharacteristic(String characteristicId) {
      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = findCharacteristicById(characteristicId);
      if (characteristic == null) return;
      mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Quintin, i am a beginner so i don't know what a 'ble' is and how to make it work with raspberry pi ??

Comment: and should i purchase Raspberry pi 3 ?

Comment: BLE stands for Bluetooth Low Energy. Raspberry Pi 0 W
 (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/) and Raspberry Pi 3 (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) boards come with the required hardware built in. BLE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) is the technology of choice for smartwatches and other personal devices that interact with smart phone

Comment: Do I need to purchase another component for ble along with raspberry pi ?

Comment: Not if you order one of the boards I gave links to in the comments above - the 3 model B or the Pi 0 W. Since I am not sure where you are from you would need to find a supplier that you can order from. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as the answer (Green tick near the top of my answer).

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Thanks for the sample code, I am a newbie to Raspberry pi dev, one question, if I have to read data from a sensor and then post the result via ble, what would be the approach, will bleno suffice? as most of the sensor libraries are in python

Comment: You could try find a python bluetooth low energy (BLE) library. I prefer NodeJS simply because NodeJS is good at coordinating different things (which could include Python libraries)

Comment: Lets say I want to read a data from sensor and use bleno to broadcast it to my listeners...how do I do?